# Ignoring SameSite behaviour from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, samesite

I'm developing a Chrome extension that is going to be opening links inside of an internal CRM web application that has it's SameSite cookie set to Strict.

I'm running into an issue where when I open the links in that web application from the extension (via the codded Chrome extension popup page), the session cookie isn't being sent to the server (since the SameSite value is set to Strict). This seems like correct behaviour and SameSite is working properly.

However, is it possible to modify the "open page" request so that it sends the session cookie over when links are clicked/opened via the Chrome extension popup page?

I guess my question is it possible to modify the web requests and how to go about doing that.

Comment: In ManifestV3 you can use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) to set cookie headers.

Comment: Actually, I think I solved it via setting the "host_permissions" property in the manifest.json to the origin of the internal CRM.